# Singularity or stiff system in ParametricNDSolve

Tags: differential-equations, mathematical-optimization, parametric-functions

I have following parameters and equations(it's a complex one, please check it :) ):

```
(*definition*)
NR[expr_] := Piecewise[{{1, expr > 0}, {0, expr <= 0}}];
μm=0.67;
ks=0.28;
x2max=2039;
x3max=939.5; (*1036*)
x4max=1026; (*1050*)
x5max=360.9;
x7max=80;
kgm=0.53;
kpm=0.14;
l1 = 1;
l2 = 1;
μ = (μm*x2[t])/(
   x2[t] + ks) (1 - x7[t]/x7max) (1 - x2[t]/x2max) (1 - x3[t]/
     x4max) (1 - x4[t]/x4max) (1 - x5[t]/x5max);
q20 = m2 + μ/y2 + dq2*x2[t]/(x2[t] + k2max);
q2 = (k1*x2[t])/(x2[t] + k2) + k3 (x2[t] - x6[t])*NR[x2[t] - x6[t]];
q3 = l1*(k4*x8[t])/(x8[t] + k5) + 
   l2*k6*(x8[t] - x3[t])*NR[x8[t] - x3[t]];
q4 = m4 + μ*y4;
q5 = m5 + μ*y5;
(*equations*)

eqn = {
   x1'[t] == μ*x1[t],
   x2'[t] == -q2*x1[t],
   x3'[t] == q3*x1[t],
   x4'[t] == q4*x1[t],
   x5'[t] == q5*x1[t],
   x6'[t] == 
    1/k7*((k8*x2[t])/(x2[t] + k9) + 
       k10 (x2[t] - x6[t])*NR[x2[t] - x6[t]] - q20) - μ*x6[t],
   x7'[t] == (k11*x6[t])/(kgm (1 + x7[t]/k12) + x6[t]) - (k13*x7[t])/(
     kpm + x7[t] (1 + x7[t]/k14)) - μ*x7[t],
   x8'[t] == (k13*x7[t])/(kpm + x7[t] (1 + x7[t]/k14)) - 
     l1*k15*x8[t]/(x8[t] + k16) - 
     l2*k17 (x8[t] - x3[t]) NR[x8[t] - x3[t]] - μ*x8[t]
   };
```

Parameters and ParametricNDSolve are:

```
cond={x1[0]==0.102,x2[0]==418.2609,x3[0]==0,x4[0]==0,x5[0]==0,x6[0]== 0,x7[0]==0,x8[0]==0};
 pars={k1,k2,k3,k4,k5,k6,k7,k8,k9,k10,k11,k12,k13,k14,k15,k16,k17,m2,m4,m5,y2,y4,y5,dq2,k2max};

sol = ParametricNDSolveValue[
   Join[eqn, cond], {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5, x6, x7, x8}, {t, 0, 7}, pars,
    Method -> {"IDA", "ImplicitSolver" -> {"GMRES"}}];
```

I'm not sure about the method, but it works sometimes.

I want to minimize a target function to get the optimal value of these parameters.

```
(*Data*)
expdata={{{0, 0.102}, {0.74, 0.25444}, {1, 0.308}, {1.98, 0.48685}, {2, 0.4905}, {3, 0.8005}, {4, 1.4305}, {4.475, 1.7772499999999998`}, {5, 2.1605}, {6, 2.7405}, {6.92, 3.0855}}, {{0, 418.2609}, {0.74, 406.919586}, {1, 402.9348}, {1.98, 377.90217}, {2, 377.3913}, {3, 336.6304}, {4, 265.2174}, {4.475, 216.78806250000002`}, {5, 163.2609}, {6, 76.52174}, {6.92, 10.21739}}, {{0, 0}, {0.74, 22.394738399999998`}, {1, 30.26316}, {1.98, 48.960530999999996`}, {2, 49.34211}, {3, 57.5}, {4, 126.7105}, {4.475, 176.08551499999996`}, {5, 230.6579}, {6, 250.7895}, {6.92, 284.6053}}};

(*Target function*)
minObj[v1_?NumberQ, v2_?NumberQ, v3_?NumberQ, v4_?NumberQ, 
  v5_?NumberQ, v6_?NumberQ, v7_?NumberQ, v8_?NumberQ, v9_?NumberQ, 
  v10_?NumberQ, v11_?NumberQ, v12_?NumberQ, v13_?NumberQ, 
  v14_?NumberQ, v15_?NumberQ, v16_?NumberQ, v17_?NumberQ, 
  v18_?NumberQ, v19_?NumberQ, v20_?NumberQ, v21_?NumberQ, 
  v22_?NumberQ, v23_?NumberQ, v24_?NumberQ, v25_?NumberQ] := 
 Sum[Sum[Abs[
     sol[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, 
         v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25][[i]][
       expdata[[i, j, 1]]] - expdata[[i, j, 2]]]/
    Abs[expdata[[i, j, 2]]], {j, 2, 11}], {i, 1, 3}]
```

And when I use NMinimize, it warns "Singularity or stiff system",
so I try to set the initital points for NMinimize as below:

```
(*One valid parameter set*)
minparsValue = {56.1633, 4.6239, 203.853, 128.468, 1.4704, 50.5692, 
   6.5778, 56.9537, 1.0529, 2100.57, 16.8822, 249.53, 32.9252, 0.7654,
    13.1999, 29.8004, 85.7896, 2.9292, \[Minus]0.8212, 5.2296, 0.0103,
    22.391, 12.7145, 40.1832, 9.0077};

(*Create more sets*)
randomPoints[pts_, num_] := 
 Join[{pts}, (Table[# + RandomReal[{-10, 10}], {i, 1, num}] & /@ 
     pts) // Transpose]

(*NMinimize*)
Block[{temp = 0, c = 0}, NMinimize[minObj[
Sequence[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, 
    v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25]], {v1, v2, 
   v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17,
    v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25}, 
  Method -> {"DifferentialEvolution", 
    "InitialPoints" -> randomPoints[minparsValue, 4], 
    "SearchPoints" -> 4}, 
  EvaluationMonitor :> {NotebookDelete[temp], 
    temp = PrintTemporary[c++];}]
```

Sometimes there's a valid output, but most of the time it keeps popping warnings.

So, I'm wondering is there any way to solve the equation? Many thanks for reading!

**Update:**

```
NMinimize[minObj[
Sequence[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, 
   v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25]], {v1, v2, 
  v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, 
  v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, v24, v25}, MaxIterations -> 5, 
 Method -> {"NelderMead", "InitialPoints" -> {minparsValue}}, 
 EvaluationMonitor :> {Print[v1, v2, v3, v4, v5, v6, v7, v8, v9, v10, 
     v11, v12, v13, v14, v15, v16, v17, v18, v19, v20, v21, v22, v23, 
     v24, v25];}]
```

The output is:

> Step 1: {56.1633,4.6239,203.853,128.468,1.4704,50.5692,6.5778,56.9537,1.0529,2100.57,16.8822,249.53,32.9252,0.7654,13.1999,29.8004,85.7896,2.9292,-0.8212,5.2296,0.0103,22.391,12.7145,40.1832,9.0077}

> Step 2: {0.870932,0.645043,0.782446,-0.484861,-0.165669,0.786984,0.360874,-0.755282,0.188728,0.503921,0.558626,0.299901,-0.304018,0.286253,0.335431,0.081131,0.24267,0.362557,-0.200533,0.875082,0.416675,-0.353446,0.627328,-0.413779,-0.39947}

Since this set of parameters are probably not domain where have no singularities, it stops with errors. How can I solve this problem?

Comment: Why use the method IDA? It looks like an explicit ODE system, not a DAE, no? One thing to figure out is whether it's stiffness or a singularity. If ODE and stiffness, try `Method -> "StiffnessSwitching"`. If a singularity, I suppose you'll have to figure out how to tell `NMinimize` to stay in the parameter domain where there are no singularities.

Comment: We can search around stable solution, for example, with `randomPoints[pts_, num_] := 
  Join[{pts}, (Table[# + RandomReal[{-1, 1}], {i, 1, num}] & /@ pts) //
     Transpose];`

Comment: @MichaelR2, I'm using the StiffnessSwitching method right now. However, when I set the initial points for any NMinilize method, after few steps the parameters jump to [-1,1], I add some descriptions in the question, thanks for your help!